# STM32F407 Discovery Board DCMI to SPI Output

Tags: stm32, spi, camera, dma

I am currently attempting to use a STM32F407 Discovery board to display images captured with a OV2640 CMOS detector on a ILI9341 2.2" TFT SPI LCD.  My goal right now is to take a single snapshot and display it on the LCD.  As I understand, an image must be passed through the DCMI to the DMA2 Stream 1.  From DMA2 it can then be transmitted to the SPI ports where it can send the pixel data to the LCD. 
However, I am quite confused on how to facilitate the DMA transfer to the SPI interface. Once the data is received in the DMA, is it stored under a specific memory address which I can access?

Does anybody have any methods for transferring pixel data from DCMI -> DMA2 -> SPI1? I have been stumped by this for quite a few days and cannot find any resources online which explain this transfer.

Comment: If you had the correct (and mandatory) datasheets you would not be asking such questions. We cannot substitute for the huge amount of details the datasheets have. Not having them is often a show stopper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: I haven't done anything with screens myself, so I'm not sure, if data types returned by camera are ok for screen. But I do have working camera based on STM32F427 and OV5640.

When fetching image from DCMI via DMA, you have to pass in an address pointer, where the image is going to be stored. This transfer is usually synchronized with VSYNC to ensure correct frame. Once DMA transfer is done, you use the same address pointer to start DMA transmit to the screen (HAL_SPI_Transmit_DMA(&picBuff, size)). It's better to do it outside DMA IRQ, but might work from within it as well, depends on overall setup.

If you have data type mismatch between camera and screen (YUV vs RGB565 or whatever formats), you have to convert the data before. Or just request the correctly formatted data from camera (I think OV2640 supported quite a few data type outputs)